# Count number of rows in SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to view how many rows there are based on a SQL query using PHP.

I seem to be able query the database and return fields from a row but can't seem to find out how many rows there are based on the same query.

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'MyUsername';
    $pass = 'MyPassword';
    $database = 'MyDatabase';


    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass ,$database);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE test='123' AND test2='456'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "$num_rows Rows\n"; 

    mysqli_close($con);

      ?>
```

All it returns is the text **Rows** on the screen, without the number of rows at the start.

Like I said, this same query works and returns a value if I try and select a row using:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo $row["test"];
   }
```

Anyone know why it won't return the number of rows?

Comment: Why do you use `mysql_num_rows` for a `mysqli_query`?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` is not MySQLi function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using MySQLi. Because of you don't have a mysql query, mysql_num_rows doesn't return desired value.
You have to replace your mysql function with mysqli equal:

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, this fixed my issue.. Something so simple!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Mysqli` to you should use `mysqli_num_rows`

> $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE test='123' AND test2='456'");
>        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

If you want only `count` then you can directly use `count(*)` like this:-

> $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE test='123' AND test2='456'");
>
> echo $result;

Answer (score 1):

I'll do some thing like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE test='123' AND test2='456'");
echo $result
```